# Task queues and Datastore read and writes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Objectify in my google cloud endpoints module , My endpoint project handles most of my datastore read and write ops , but i wanted to know if it is an efficient design practice to use Task queues to wrap a read or write operation on the datastore in google app engine .

Comment: Why do you want to wrap reads/writes in tasks? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Im just trying curios if it could help speed up read and write ops .

Answer (score 3):

All the data necessary for a task execution has to be written somewhere, and the App Engine persists this data in a task queue backed by the same Datastore. Unless your write operation involves number crunching, URL fetching, external API calls, updates of hundreds on entities, or some other expensive logic, there is no advantage to wrapping a write call in a task.

Wrapping read calls in tasks is impossible in most cases as you lose an ability to return this data in the same call.

Comment: Thanks , like I said it was just a thought .Are you an appengine dev ?.

Comment: You can click on my name to see that I am not :) But I am using App Engine for many years.

Comment: Ok great just started using it ,loving it .

Comment: Hi guys. I have question. Is there a way to modify Datastore Admin Backup Built-in Task Queue? Here's the link of my question. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698872/modify-datastore-admin-backup-built-in-task-queue

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use write-behind-cache if you want to speed up your writes. There's a little chance that you will lose your data, but you will dramatically speed up the write speed (as seen by user).

The idea is to write entity only into memcache first, so user will not wait for actual datastore write, and then pick up that memcached entity by task queue/cron and write it into datastore.

Comment: I'm using objectify @cache annotation ,so I think the cache thing is handled ,I don't understand ur concept of write-behind-cache tho .

Comment: Actually handles async writes transparently (if you don't use.now()), you wont get any feedback (like a created entity id) though.

Comment: Ok fire and forget u mean , I do understand but there are certain operations that it won't apply to a typical example is when u  r handling a transaction u might need to get the Id of one object and reference it to another object .Thanks for the tip tho .