# Modify Datastore Admin Backup Built-in Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-golang, datastore-admin

I'm new to Datastore. Currently, I'm using datastore admin to backup my data but I'm wondering if we can modify or override the built-in task queue on datastore admin `/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?`

What I want to do when exporting the data from datastore is that I would only need to export the data that has specific date range that I specify. I saw on the documentation that you can pass a parameter to the URL. Is its possible to pass the parameter on the date range like this one?
`/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=MyBackup&StartDate=12-01-20&EndDate=01-12-21`.

Please let me know if I miss something.

Comment: Are you asking this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/datastore-admin-backups ? its depreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore admin is deprecated. You should upgrade to the [datastore export service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).

But to answer your question, the datastore admin app hosted at /_ah/datastore_admin is an internal app which you cannot modify. However, you could write a custom handler to kick off the backup process, thereby passing in the params you need.

GAE example using taskqueue API:

```
params = {
    'StartDate': start_date,
    'EndDate': end_date
}

taskqueue.add(
    url='/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create',
    params=params, 
    target='ah-builtin-python-bundle'
)
```

Again, I do not recommend this approach, as the service has been long deprecated and is due to disappear at any moment.